# Access on premise rest/soap services from azure functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

we have a on premise restful and few soap based services. which needs to be accessed from azure function app. Need to know what are the ways we can access on premise services from function app.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head you have a few options:

- Make the on-prem services public facing
- Create a VPN connection and [Integrate a Function App with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet)
- Look into [Azure Service Bus relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/)

> Azure Relay service facilitates hybrid applications between on-premises and cloud environments within a corporate enterprise network and the public cloud, without having to open a firewall connection or require intrusive changes to a corporate network infrastructure.

You might be looking for a way to [Expose an on-premises WCF REST service to external client by using Azure WCF Relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-relay-tutorial)